# Finding complex roots through mixed methods

Tags: complex-analysis

$z^2+\left(1-i\right)z+\left(i-1\right)=0$

My answer: $\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+i\pm \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+2}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}i\right)\right)$

Textbook answer $\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+i\pm \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+2}-\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}i\right)\right)$

My troubles begin with the square root $\sqrt{4-6i} = x+iy$

I actually was able to get the textbook answer by considering purely $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ BUT
I am unable to get the same answer using the $2xy = -6$ to find $y$ because I always get a $\frac{1}{3}$ after rationalizing. I have actually always done it this way: a mixture of considering $x^2 - y^2 = 4 \tag{1}$ and the silmultanoues equations formed by $x^2 +y^2 = 2\sqrt{13} \tag{2}$, then putting $x$ into $2xy = -6$. For this particular question, I always get $\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+i\pm \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+2}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}i\right)\right)$

When I go the correct answer, it was by adding AND substracting $[1]$ and $[2]$ to determine $x$ and $y$ separately. Why wont the mother method work though? Is it because rationalising with nested square root and the $\pm$ and complex number $i$ all at the same time gets wierd/messy/undefined?

Comment: Isn't my answer helpful? If needed, I could add more explanations in my answer. Do you still have the same question as the one written in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085340/plus-minus-case-for-complex-number-square-roots)? If so, then note that, in our question here, the $\pm$ issue does not matter because, in either way, we get the textbook answer.

Comment: Also, you might want to see [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number).

Comment: Sorry, yes it is helpful. The mistake I made is extremely obvious and stupid. Basically the rationalizing part I made a silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting $$x=\pm\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+2}$$
we have, using $2xy=-6$,
$$\begin{align}y&=-\frac{3}{x}=\mp\frac{3}{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}+2}}=\mp\sqrt{\frac{9}{\sqrt{13}+2}}
\\\\&=\mp\sqrt{\frac{9(\sqrt{13}-2)}{(\sqrt{13}+2)(\sqrt{13}-2)}}=\mp\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}\end{align}$$